# How to flatten if-else-if-statements with caching in Scala 3?

Tags: scala, option-type, scala-3

I have the following very ugly nesting of if-statements that involve slow operations (`tryFindResult` and `tryFindOtherResult`) that I need to execute as little as possible. Just to give some context, it's part of a parser that looks at the current line (`line`) at some position (`i`). Each case in the if-statement produces side-effects (increases `i`).

```scala
if (cond) {
    // increase i
} else {
    val maybeResult: Option[Result] = tryFindResult(line, i)
    if (maybeResult.nonEmpty) {
        // depending on `maybeResult`, increase i
    } else {
        val (newOffset, maybeOtherResult): (Int, Option[Result2]) = tryFindOtherResult(line, i)
        if (maybeOtherResult.nonEmpty) {
            // depending on `maybeOtherResult`, increase i
        } else {
            // i = newOffset
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can flatten this? As far as I know, Scala has no inline assignment syntax like `if (val o = tryFindOtherResult && o.nonEmpty)`, right?
Note that moving `tryFindResult` and `tryFindOtherResult` to the beginning of the program would solve everything, but these are long-running operations that I can't execute unconditionally (the program is part of a parser and needs to jump forward in the last if/else-branch to avoid quadratic complexity).

Are there tricks with match statements, or `map`/`flatMap`/`getOrElse` on Options that I can use to avoid this kind of nesting?

Comment: Can you give a more complete example? What exactly does "// Do things" do? Is it side-effecting, or are you returning a value?

Comment: @marstran I adjusted the question. Each case has side-effects on `i`. Unfortunately I can't post the actual code. I think I'd be most interested in a general solution: how to write nested `if`s with caching while keeping the control flow the same. Maybe there is a syntax for inline assignment I don't know about or an elegant way to do just that, or a way to use the `match`-statement to make the structure more elegant.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the methods defined on the `Option` type and its companion object. I'm not entirely sure of the semantics of each case, but it would roughly look as follows:

```
final case class Result(i: Int)
final case class Result2(i: Int)

def tryFindResult(line: Int, i: Int): Option[Result] =
  if (line == 42) Some(Result(42)) else None
def tryFindOtherResult(line: Int, i: Int): (Int, Option[Result2]) =
  if (line == 47) (47, Some(Result2(47))) else (-1, None)

def method(cond: Boolean, line: Int, i: Int, fallback: Int): Int =
  Option
    .when(cond)(i + 1)
    .orElse(tryFindResult(line, i).map(_.i + 1))
    .orElse {
      val (_, result) = tryFindOtherResult(line, i)
      result.map(_.i + 1)
    }
    .getOrElse(fallback)

assert(method(cond = true, line = 42, i = 0, fallback = 100) == 1)
assert(method(cond = true, line = 42, i = 100, fallback = 100) == 101)
assert(method(cond = false, line = 42, i = 0, fallback = 100) == 43)
assert(method(cond = false, line = 47, i = 0, fallback = 100) == 48)
assert(method(cond = false, line = 33, i = 0, fallback = 100) == 100
```

Notice that the fallback passed to `orElse` and the function passed to `when` are both *by-name parameters* (see the documentation [here](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html)), which makes them evaluated lazily, i.e. only if they need to be used.

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/aY5MVZHvS1movIgUVoOEzg/11).

You can read more about `orElse` [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/3.3.0/scala/Option.html#orElse-bfc) and about `when` [here](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/3.3.0/scala/Option$.html#when-a9e).

It looks like you actually need to mutate a variable. Consider the option of keeping most of your code as is, if you realize that the usage of the methods I suggested obscures the side effects. Sometimes a nested `if` might be precisely what you need.